# Unable to perform edit operation in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am very new bee to ruby on rails, i have just created a small project which add,update and delete a record from mysql db

I am able to successfully add and delete record from mysql db from ruby application

But the issue is only when i try to update the existing record

My code is as follows,

## Controller:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
def list
      @books = Book.find(:all)
   end
   def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
   end
   def create
      @book = Book.new(params[:book])
      if @book.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
   def edit
      @book = Book.find(:all)

      @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
   end
   def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
      else
         @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end
   def delete
      Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end
   def show_subjects
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

## List HTML:

```
<% if @books.blank? %>
<p>There are not any books currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current books in our system</p>
<ul id="books">
<% @books.each do |c| %>
<li>
<%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%>

<b><%= link_to "edit",  {:action => 'edit', :id => c.id} %></b>

<b> <%= link_to "Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => c.id},
:confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" %></b>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add new Book", {:action => 'new' }%></p>


Edit HTML:
=========
<h1>Edit Book Detail</h1>
<%= form_tag(:action=> "update") do%>

<p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
<p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
<%= text_field 'book', 'price' %></p>
<p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
<%= collection_select(:book, :subject_id,
                         @subjects, :id, :name) %></p>
<p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'book', 'description' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Save changes" %>
<%end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list' } %>
```

I am getting the following exception when i try to edit a record from URL `http://localhost:3000/book/edit/5`,

```
Showing C:/app/app/views/book/edit.html where line #5 raised:

undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x33315c0>
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <%= form_tag(:action=> "update") do%>
3: 
4: <p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
5: <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
6: <p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
7: <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %></p>
8: <p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
```

BTW i am using rails3,ruby1.2 and mysql5.5.

As i am in a learning curve, it will be very useful if some one can help me in this issue.

Comment: You mean Ruby 1.9.2, not 1.2, right?

Comment: Also `find(:all)` is deprecated in favor of `all`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're loading all the book records when the usual intention of the `edit` method is to edit one of them.

To fix this, you should define a `before_filter` hook that handles loading records:

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
  # Set a handler for loading the book for most actions, except those
  # where loading a single book is not relevant.
  before_filter :load_book, :except => [ :index, :new, :create ]

  def edit
    @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
  end

  def update
    # Call the update_attributes method that will throw an exception if
    # an error occurs.
    @book.update_attributes!(params[:book])

    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    # This exception is triggered if there was an error saving the record
    # because of a validation problem.

    # Trigger 'edit' action
    edit
    # Render as if on 'edit' page
    render :action => 'edit'
  end

protected
  def load_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

As a note, any time you call either `find(:all)` or `all` on a model, you run the risk of using up all the system memory and crashing both your application and the server it's running on. Pagination is absolutely essential unless you can be certain the number of records is small.

Using a `before_filter` makes it a lot easier to consolidate your various redundant `find` calls into one place and can make error handling a lot simpler.